# use a free domain name from dot.tk to test my website on my VM

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I have setup a linux VM on my local computer. I have a free domain name from .tk. Is it possible for me to use that domain to make my site visible to the world to test it? If so what would I need to do?

As of now my website is only visible from my host.

Thank you.